# Same url format in different controllers with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I am having difficulties with routings in ruby on rails. I have same url format in different controllers and I am trying to send params to `site controller` but it goes to `pages controller` instead. Any help?

**Route.rb**

```
resources :sites, :path => '', :except => [:index] do
  resources :pages, :path => '' do
  end
end
```

When I run `rails routes` command I am getting something look like:

```
site_pages GET    /:site_id(.:format)            pages#index
site GET          /:id(.:format)                 sites#show
```

**View**

`<%= link_to 'GO', site_path(site) %>`

This code should go to the `site#show` but it goes to `pages#index` and it gives me this error message below:

```
 NoMethodError in PagesController#index 
 undefined method `site_id' for nil:NilClass

 Parameters:
 {"site_id"=>"site A"}
```

**I have tried:**

`<%= link_to '', site_path(site), :controller => "sites", :action => "show"%>`

`<%= link_to '', site_path(id: site.id)%>`

but it doesn't work. Any help will be very appreciate

Comment: `/:site_id` and `/:id` are indistinguishable from a routing perspective. So, anything you *think* should be resolving to `sites#show` is (correctly) resolving to `pages#index`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jvillian's comment, your routes aren't functional.

Imagine an user wants to see the site with `id` 1. She could type in the URL `my_domain.com/1`. Now, she wants to check that site's pages, so she types in `my_domain.com/1`. How can Rails know what is she referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Since pages is nested inside of sites, you'll (usually) need to have a site to have pages. To accomplish this in your scenario, remove the `:path => ''` from the pages resource. This will give you routes that look like this:

```
site_pages GET    /:site_id/pages(.:format)          pages#index
site       GET    /:id(.:format)                     sites#show
```

Then, you'll need to have a site id anytime you want to access/create its pages. Keep in mind, though, that if you pass a route like `mydomain.com/anything_here`, you're going to get directed to the sites#show action.